# Need a cloud hosting for a modular project

Tags: cloud, hosting, scalability

I'm searching for an auto-scalable (with parameters) cloud hosting solution for a modular project (rest, web and db) where each module has to scale by it's own and they have to be able to see each other.

If it can be deployed with Docker it will be just perfect.

Any tips?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

AWS Elastic Beanstalk would be a good start - https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/

Answer (score 2):

Jelastic PaaS provides auto-clustered solutions deployed with Docker, such as [GlassFish](https://github.com/jelastic-jps/glassfish) cluster, [MySQL master-slave](https://github.com/jelastic-jps/mysql-cluster) replicated databases, [WordPress](https://github.com/jelastic-jps/wordpress-cluster) or [Magento](https://github.com/jelastic-jps/magento/tree/master/magento2-php7-varnish-mysql-redis-memcache-storage) clusters and many others. They are automatically installed and scaled.

Also, you can run standalone [Docker Engine](https://blog.jelastic.com/2017/11/16/docker-engine-automatic-install-swarm-connect/) or [Swarm](https://github.com/jelastic-jps/docker-native/tree/master/docker-swarm) cluster with automatic scaling configured by default.